# Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.WebApi.BuildHttpClient UpdateDefinitionAsync - add step

Tags: c#, visual-studio, tfs, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

Tfs 2017 server

I want to add a step to the existing steps, but the build definition Steps collection is null when deSerialized the Json string in to BuildDefinition object. Downloaded Json string has the steps as "build" propery.

How to add a build step to the existing build definitions, in our org, there are around 500 build definitions, it is a humongous task to add manually.

Please advise

\packages\Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.Client.16.153.0\lib\net45\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build2.WebApi.dll

var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);

//problem is - results.Steps is null. property is deprecated.

// want to add a step to the existing steps

var task2 = Task.Run(async () => { await bhc.UpdateDefinitionAsync(result, definitionId: bd.Id, project: bd.Project.Id); }); task2.Wait();

Comment: This is the problem task groups were designed to solve. Replace repeated steps with task groups.

Comment: Since you are using the TFS 2017, you need to reference this version ：`15.112.x` of the package instead of  `16.153.0`.  Here is  [a doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/concepts/dotnet-client-libraries?view=azure-devops#package-and-tfs-version-mapping-table) you could refer to. Can you share more relevant code parts?  This helps us understand what you have done.

Comment: On the other hand, in addition to C# sample, you can also use the API to update the Build definition. You can get the corresponding api through network traffic(Browser F12).It might be more convenient.